# Another join&where situation in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I tried to look at a similar problem but couldn't find it (feel free to close it as duplicate if I missed a link).

Here's my structure :

```
subscriptions (id, day, site_id)
sites (id, name, pole_id)
poles (id, name, type_id)
poletypes (id, name)
```

And here's my query :

```
SELECT sub.id FROM `subscriptions` sub 
LEFT JOIN sites s ON sub.site_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN poles p ON p.site_id = s.id 
WHERE sub.day BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-30' AND s.id = 2 AND p.type_id = 3
```

To simplify, I want the subscriptions occured between `2013-01-01` and `2013-01-30`, that occurred in the Site id `2` and in the Pole type_id `3`.

Everything works fine, except the `pole.type_id`. I can change it to whatever I want, it is completely ignored.

Since a site can have multiple poles, I don't have a direct relation. `subscriptions` contains a link to `site` (via site_id), but I do the other work around for pole, it's `poles` that have a direct link to `site`, hence ignoring the `type_id` constraint.

But then, how can I do to filter by `type_id` ?

Comment: can u add the fiddle with your current result set and in question add desired result set so it will be helpfull to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to join the necessary records instead to join the whole table

```
SELECT sub.id FROM `subscriptions` sub 
LEFT JOIN sites s ON sub.site_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN poles p ON (p.site_id = s.id  AND p.type_id = 3 ) 
WHERE sub.day BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-30' AND s.id = 2
```

using **LEFT JOIN poles p ON (p.site_id = s.id  AND p.type_id = 3 )** will join poles table where **p.type_id = 3**

Other way you can use the subselect to your query

```
SELECT q.id FROM (
    SELECT sub.id,p.type_id  FROM `subscriptions` sub 
    LEFT JOIN sites s ON sub.site_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN poles p ON (p.site_id = s.id) 
    WHERE sub.day BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-30' AND s.id = 2
) q WHERE type_id = 3
```

Hope it works fine and filter out the results you want to filter by type_id

Comment: On your second exemple, your sub select returns two columns, is that normal (it should fail since you expect one column as your master query, right ?)

Comment: yes it is normal because in the parent query i have to filter with the column `p.type_id` if i will not select this column in subquery then i am not able to filter in parent query therefore i have to select both the columns

Comment: Oh ok good ! Thanks for the explanation :) I found the solution, and it was dumb, something I didn't indicated here (I had a link to site_id, but I should have used an other table that was doing a better joining, which I didn't included in my question, it was impossible for you to find it ;)) I'll close my answer but I'll give you a +1 for your time, sorry for that.